# Entity Framework 4.1 doesn't load relationships after SaveChanges?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I'm relatively new to EF. It appears that related table data isn't available after I call SaveChanges.

Let's say that I have a database with the following tables: User, Feature, and FeatureUser. FeatureUser ties User and Feature records together. I have a method which accepts a Feature object and it populates a list with User.name values based on the FeatureUser table. This works fine:

```
using (var db = new projectModel())
{
  feature f = db.features.First();
  populateList(f);
}

private void populateList(feature f)
{
  foreach(featureuser fu in f.featureusers)
    addToList(fu.user.name);
}
```

The important point in the code above is that I get back to the User.name value via the FeatureUser table's built-in link back to the User table. What doesn't work is to create new FeatureUser records, then save them, then attempt to follow that same process:

```
using (var db = new projectModel())
{
  feature f = db.features.First();
  foreach(int newuserid in somearray)
  {
    featureuser nfu = new featureuser();
    nfu.featureid = f.id;
    nfu.userid = newuserid;
    f.featureusers.add(nfu);
  }
  db.SaveChanges();
  populateList(f); // null reference error on fu.user.name
}
```

Is there a way to tell EF to resolve all those handy built-in relationship collections once I've established and saved the foreign keys needed to create the relationships?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The entity instances returned by EF are actually proxies. They contain logic to lazy load the navigational properties. But when you new up instance of `featureuser` it does not have that logic because it does not have that lazy loading logic.

Hence let EF create a proxy instance instead.

```
  foreach(int newuserid in somearray)
  {
    //create proxy instance
    var nfu = db.featureusers.Create();

    nfu.featureid = f.id;
    nfu.userid = newuserid;
    f.featureusers.add(nfu);
  }
```

Comment: This worked for me, however its certainly a lot more ugly than doing `var a = new db.table() { prop = value; prop1 = value1 }`. Is there a nicer way of doing this? My table has a lot of props.